# How to make a side by side clustered chart using PROC GHART in SAS?

Tags: sas

The following code gives a side by side chart

```
data a;
input Salesman $ 1-6 Year Sales;
datalines;
Bob    2009  6
Anna   2009  8
Carl   2009  9
Bob    2010  7
Anna   2010  9
Carl   2010 10
;
run;

axis1 label=none order=(0 to 30 by 10) minor=none offset=(0,0);
axis2 label=none offset=(15,15);

legend1 position=(right middle) across=1 label=none
shape=bar(.13in,.13in) order=('Carl' 'Bob' 'Anna');

pattern1 v=s c=yellow;
pattern2 v=s c=orange;
pattern3 v=s c=red;

proc gchart data=a;
vbar year / discrete type=sum sumvar=sales
raxis=axis1 maxis=axis2 width=15 space=8
noframe autoref clipref cref=graycc
subgroup=Salesman legend=legend1;
run;
```

However it plots the bars one on the top of another. The bottomline I have a `stacked` , but I need `clustered` graph .

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PROC GCHART gives me a headache!!!  I second Robslink.com  as a good resource for SAS/GRAPH examples.  I think your code is almost there, try this (change VBAR to use SALESMAN instead of YEAR  and also add the GROUP option.

```
proc gchart data=a;
vbar /*year*/ Salesman / discrete type=sum sumvar=sales
raxis=axis1 maxis=axis2 width=15 space=8
noframe autoref clipref cref=graycc
subgroup=Salesman group=year legend=legend1;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible in gchart, but I suggest sgplot instead; it's much easier.  One example from Sanjay Patel's blog, [Graphically Speaking](http://blogs.sas.com/content/graphicallyspeaking/2013/09/07/bar-charts-with-stacked-and-cluster-groups/):

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.prdsale;
  title 'Actual Sales by Product and Quarter';
  vbar product / response=actual group=quarter groupdisplay=cluster 
                 dataskin=gloss;
  xaxis display=(nolabel);
  yaxis grid;
  run;
```

Note `groupdisplay=cluster`, which is what's making it clustered (not `groupdisplay=stacked`).

For your data:

```
proc sgplot data=a;
 vbar year/group=salesman response=sales groupdisplay=cluster;
run;
```

I believe the `gchart` answer is that you need to use the `group` statement to create clusters (as opposed to `subgroup` which is creating the stacked element).  You also need a functional `gaxis` for that to work.  See [this Robslink.com example](http://robslink.com/SAS/democd6/bar2_info.htm) for more detail.  (Robslink.com should probably be the first place to go for `gchart` and `gplot` help; Rob Allison, who works at SAS Institute, maintains it and has an incredible set of charts there, plus sample code.)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I cannot use sgplot because of JMV issues on my site. You are right I have a stacked graph, but I need a clustered one, I updated my question with an image